# Given 4 sets: $A, B, C, D$, Prove that if $A \triangle B \subseteq D, B \triangle C \subseteq D$, then $A \triangle C \subseteq D$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Given four sets: $A, B, C, D$, suppose that $$A \triangle B \subseteq D  \ \land  \  B \triangle C \subseteq D  $$
**Prove:**  $A \triangle C \subseteq D$

[As  $\triangle$ means symmetric difference]

***My Attempt:***

Notice that $A \triangle B =  (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) = (A \cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$

Therefore: $\left((A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)\right) \text{ and } \left((B\cup C)\setminus (B\cap C)\right) \subseteq D$

### ***EDIT:***

I'd like to prove: $(A \triangle C) \subseteq (A\triangle B)\cup(B\triangle C)$
$$\left((A\triangle B)\cup(B \triangle C)\right)=(A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)\cup(B\cup C)\setminus(B\cap C)$$ $$ =(A\cup B)\cup(B\cup C)\setminus(A\cap B)\cup(B\cap C)$$ 
$$=B\cup(A\cup C)\setminus B\cap(A\cup C)$$

$   \   $

**Now** -- can I say that $(A\cup C)\setminus(A\cap C) \subseteq (B\cup(A\cup C)\setminus B\cap(A\cup C)$?

### ***my previous attempt:***

Notice that $A \triangle B =  (A \setminus B) \cup (B \setminus A) = (A \cup B)\setminus (A\cap B)$

Therefore: $\left((A\cup B)\setminus(A\cap B)\right) \text{ and } \left((B\cup C)\setminus (B\cap C)\right) \subseteq D$

**I'll divide into cases:**

**I.** let $x \in (A\triangle B) \land x\notin C \to x\in (A\setminus C) \subseteq (A \triangle C)$

Notice that  $A\triangle B \subseteq D \to x\in D$, therefore $x \in A\triangle C \land x\in D$

**II.** let $x'\in (B \triangle C) \land \  x'\notin A \ $, then $x'\in (C\setminus A) \subseteq (A\triangle C)$ **as** $(B\triangle C) \subseteq D \to \ x'\in D$

**III.** Let $x'' \in (B\cap C) \land x\notin A$ Then $x\in (B\setminus 
A)\subseteq (A \triangle B) \subseteq D$, Hence $x'' \in D$

**Notice that**  $x'' \in (C\setminus A) \subseteq (A \triangle C)$ , so $x'' \in D \land x''\in (A\triangle C)$.

*I don't know if I covered all possible cases (and can't find a way to do so. using contradiction didn't helped).
What can be done at such case?*

Comment: Verify that $(A\Delta C) \subset (A\Delta B) \cup (B\Delta C)$.

Comment: When showing that $X\subseteq Y$, you usually start with "Let $x\in X$", and end with "and therefore, $x\in Y$.", with some reasoning in-between. In this case, you therefore ought to start with "let $x\in A\Delta C$".

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy but the problem is I can't prove that as I'm not sure how to cover all possibilities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proof is possibly good, but once you know associativity of symmetric difference, you can realize that
$$
(A\mathbin{\triangle}B)\mathbin{\triangle}(B\mathbin{\triangle}C)=
A\mathbin{\triangle}(B\mathbin{\triangle}B)\mathbin{\triangle}C=
A\mathbin{\triangle}\emptyset\mathbin{\triangle}C=A\mathbin{\triangle}C
$$
Thus you only need to show that $X\subseteq D$ and $Y\subseteq D$ implies $X\mathbin{\triangle}Y\subseteq D$, which is clear because
$$
X\mathbin{\triangle}Y\subseteq X\cup Y
$$

A lower level proof. Let $x\in A\mathbin{\triangle}C$. Either “$x\in A$ and $x\notin C$” or “$x\in C$ and $x\notin A$”.

First case: $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$. If $x\in B$, then $x\in B\mathbin{\triangle}C$. If $x\notin B$, then $x\in A\mathbin{\triangle}B$.

Second case: similar.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a very easy proof. I think you are getting lost among all those fancy math symbols

Let $x \in A\triangle C$. Therefore $x \in A$ and $x \notin C$ are both true.

If $x \in B, x \in B \triangle C \subseteq D$

Otherwise, $x \notin B$. This implies $x \in A \triangle B \subseteq D$

Comment: From $x\in A\triangle C$ it does not follow that $x\in A$ and $x\notin C$.

Comment: yes, regarding @ChristianBlatter comment -- $x \in A$ and $x \notin C \to x\in A\triangle C$, but the other direction isn't necessarily true